# Freescale t4240qds: Serial Rapidio API

Tags: c, api

I am trying to develope a protocol stack.As for now i have build the kernel and enabled the Rapidio interfaces in t4240 board. Where can i get the Serial Rapidio API for freescale t4240qds board?

Answer (score 0):

You need to download the Linux SDK for QorIQ processors. Version 1.7 is the current release as of this writing. Its avalable [here](http://www.freescale.com/webapp/sps/site/prod_summary.jsp?code=SDKLINUX&site_preference=normal). You will need a freescale.com account if you don't have one already, which is free.